# How can I transfer my geojson data to a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database, geojson

I generated with javascript geojson data. Now I want to transfer the data of this geojson file to a mysql database. I know that mysql has a function for geojson data but I'm really new in this topic so I don't know how to use it.
So my question is how I can transfer my geojson data to a mysql database. I would like that one column shows the type (Point/Polygon/...), one the features if there are some (color,...) and one column for the coordinates.
And perhaps is there also a possibility to transfer these data automatically?

At the moment I tried this:

```
SET @point_o_from_geoJSON := ST_GeomFromGeoJSON( '{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[8.721926,49.856657]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[8.428072,50.052724],[8.428072,50.190024],[8.807062,50.190024],[8.807062,50.052724],[8.428072,50.052724]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[9.177812,50.151338]}}]}' ); # geometry from geoJSON 
select ST_AsText(@point_o_from_geoJSON) AS `point_o_from_geoJSON`;
```

But then all the information are in one column: [data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etyZz.png)

I tried to split the geometries with JSON_TABLE but I am struggling with the different numbers of coordinates of each geometry. That was my try (from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html):

```
  SELECT *
     FROM
       JSON_TABLE(
         '{"type":"FeatureCollection","features": 
          [{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry": 
          {"type":"Point","coordinates":[8.721926,49.856657]}},
          {"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry": 
          {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[8.428072,50.052724],[8.428072,50.190024],[8.807062,50.190024],[8.807062,50.052724],[8.428072,50.052724]]]}},
          {"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry": 
          {"type":"Point","coordinates":[9.177812,50.151338]}}]}',
         '$[*]' COLUMNS(
         top_ord For ordinality,
         typeID VARCHAR(10) Path '$.type',
         nested path '$.features[*]' columns (
            itemtype varchar(10) path '$.type',
            prop varchar(50) path '$.properties',
            ord for ordinality,
            nested path '$.geometry[*]' columns (
                itemstype varchar(10) path '$.type',
                ordi for ordinality,
                nested path '$.coordinates[*]' columns (coord varchar(10) path '$')
                 )
                )
             ) 
          ) as jt;
```

Comment: *But then all the information are in one column* You put solid value into one column. Why do you think that this one combined value will split into separate values on its own? You must parse your JSON to separate geometries with according function (JSON_TABLE).

Comment: @Akina I just tried to separate the data with JSON_TABLE. But I am still struggling how I could use it because of the different number of coordinates of each geometry. I just added my tested code in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT top_ord,
       typeID,
       features_ord,
       itemtype,
       CAST(properties AS CHAR) properties,
       geometry_ord,
       itemstype,
       COALESCE(point_coordinate_ord, polygon_point_coordinate_ord) coordinate_ord,
       CAST(COALESCE(point_coordinate, polygon_point_coordinate) AS DECIMAL(10,6)) point_coordinate
FROM JSON_TABLE(
         '{"type":"FeatureCollection","features": 
          [{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry": 
           {"type":"Point","coordinates":[8.721926,49.856657]}},
           {"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry": 
           {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[8.428072,50.052724],[8.428072,50.190024],[8.807062,50.190024],[8.807062,50.052724],[8.428072,50.052724]]]}},
           {"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry": 
           {"type":"Point","coordinates":[9.177812,50.151338]}}]}',
         '$' COLUMNS(
           top_ord For ordinality,
           typeID TEXT Path '$.type',
           nested path '$.features[*]' columns (
             features_ord for ordinality,
             itemtype TEXT path '$.type',
             properties JSON path '$.properties',
             nested path '$.geometry' columns (
               geometry_ord for ordinality,
               itemstype TEXT path '$.type',
               nested path '$.coordinates[*]' COLUMNS (
                 point_coordinate_ord FOR ORDINALITY,
                 point_coordinate TEXT PATH '$'
                 ),
               nested path '$.coordinates[*][*][*]' COLUMNS (
                 polygon_point_coordinate_ord FOR ORDINALITY,
                 polygon_point_coordinate TEXT PATH '$'
                 )
               )
             )
           ) 
         ) as jt
WHERE COALESCE(point_coordinate, polygon_point_coordinate) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 1,3,6,8;
```

| top_ord | typeID | features_ord | itemtype | properties | geometry_ord | itemstype | coordinate_ord | point_coordinate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FeatureCollection | 1 | Feature | {} | 1 | Point | 1 | 8.721926 |
| 1 | FeatureCollection | 1 | Feature | {} | 1 | Point | 2 | 49.856657 |
| 1 | FeatureCollection | 2 | Feature | {} | 1 | Polygon | 1 | 8.428072 |
| 1 | FeatureCollection | 2 | Feature | {} | 1 | Polygon | 2 | 50.052724 |
| 1 | FeatureCollection | 2 | Feature | {} | 1 | Polygon | 3 | 8.428072 |
| 1 | FeatureCollection | 2 | Feature | {} | 1 | Polygon | 4 | 50.190024 |
| 1 | FeatureCollection | 2 | Feature | {} | 1 | Polygon | 5 | 8.807062 |
| 1 | FeatureCollection | 2 | Feature | {} | 1 | Polygon | 6 | 50.190024 |
| 1 | FeatureCollection | 2 | Feature | {} | 1 | Polygon | 7 | 8.807062 |
| 1 | FeatureCollection | 2 | Feature | {} | 1 | Polygon | 8 | 50.052724 |
| 1 | FeatureCollection | 2 | Feature | {} | 1 | Polygon | 9 | 8.428072 |
| 1 | FeatureCollection | 2 | Feature | {} | 1 | Polygon | 10 | 50.052724 |
| 1 | FeatureCollection | 3 | Feature | {} | 1 | Point | 1 | 9.177812 |
| 1 | FeatureCollection | 3 | Feature | {} | 1 | Point | 2 | 50.151338 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ua0mwLyE)

Comment: Thank your very much. I tried know extend your code and split the properties in author, color and text. But the fields are still empty. I changed the line `properties JSON path '$.properties',` to `nested path '$.properties' columns (properties_ord for ordinality, author TEXT path '$.author', text_content TEXT path '$.text', color TEXT path '$.color'),` and also changed the SELECT-part.
My properties in the geojson are: "properties":{"author":"rtsg","text":"earw","color":"red"}.
Can someone help me, why the fields for author, text and color remain "NULL"?

Comment: @MelinaM *why the fields for author, text and color remain "NULL"* In most cases this means that you provide incorrect paths.